# bounce effect with jqueryui and svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, svg

i have an SVG file that i would like to manipulate using JQUERYUI , effects like slide in show and hide are working but the bounce effect i just can't figure it out, anybody have any idea about that?

here is my jquery function :

```
$('#logo').on('click touchstart', function () {
      obj.play();
$('#logo').effect('bounce', {times:5}, 800); 
  });
}
```

but no effect what so ever, i know i am missing something but i just don't know what is it. 
when my function looks like this it works (with other effects)

```
$('#logo').on('click touchstart', function () {
      obj.play();
      $('#XMLID_37181_').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 50);
      $('#XMLID_37180_').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 100);
      $('#XMLID_37179_').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 150);
      $('#XMLID_37178_').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 200);
      $('#XMLID_37177_').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 250);
      $('#XMLID_37176_').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 300);
      $('#XMLID_37175_').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 350);
      $('#XMLID_37174_').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 400);
});
```

Edit 1 :

here is my whole code :

```
<html>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="blue_square"></div>
<script>
$.get('square.svg', function(data) {
$(document.body).append(data.documentElement);

$('#blue_square').on('click touchstart', function () {
    $('#blue_square').effect('bounce', {times:5}, 800); 
});
</script>
<style>
#blue_square {
    width: 472px;
    height: 472px;;
    background: #069;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
</html>
```

i dunno why the bounce effect doesn't work? what i am missing now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#logo').on('click touchstart', function () {
    $('#logo').effect('bounce', {times:5}, 800); 
});
```

```css
#logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<html><body>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="logo">
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-4 -4 8 8">
 <title>SVG animation using SMIL</title>
 <circle cx="0" cy="1" r="2" stroke="red" fill="none"> 
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0" to="360" begin="0s" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
 </circle>
 </svg>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: it works here but i am importing an svg in my code so it doesn't work with it, does the bounce effect have problems working with svg files?

Comment: I have updated the code with a svg object. It is working. Make sure you are wrapping the object inside  #logo element. If you provide a fiddle I can look into it more.